# httpcontext in windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone, httpcontext, system.web

I an pretty new to Windows phone development and I'm facing the first issue coding the first app.

I can't add a reference to system.Web and I'd like to use httpcontext, I don't know even if it's possible.

I needed to use another functionality such as httputility and that I've managed to sort using [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/HttpUtility.cs?r=961).

I have adapted that code to the windows application but for the httpcontext I just can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

AUTOANSWER:

Finally I got through it using HttpWebRequest & HttpWebResponse